# Visual Studio default value for DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have been trying to create a Windows Application Form to insert data to my SQL Server database.

I chose `DateTimePicker` to be used for `date of birth` and `start date`.

What I need is to have a `default value` of blank as if the user does not change the dates, the fixed date would not be sent to the database as default, otherwise it would simply send over today's date as default if not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this on the backend:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myDate.Text) == false)
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value =  DateTime.Today();
        }
```

Or if that doesn't work for you on the back end assign the value like so:

```
myDate.Text = DateTime.Today().ToString();
```

EDIT: Response to last question. Try this:

```
myDateDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
myDateDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Comment: any chance i can have this sorted through design tab instead of codes? also none of the codes you provided worked :(

Comment: All of that is good code that I've used before and just needs to be adjusted to your project. You're going to have to post a sample of your code if you want something specific to your environment otherwise we are shooting in the dark.

Comment: Dear Roro, there is no code related to the DateTimePicker. I am simply asking if I can have its default value as blank, so if the user forgot to change it, or for instance the user simply did not have the date to insert, my application would not send in today's date! that is all im asking.

Comment: Try this.   myDateDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    myDateDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";

Comment: `SmallDateTIme` isn't used, it's essentially a legacy feature. [DateTimePicker.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a *DateTime*, not a string. There's no reason to get or set the date as a string. `Format` is only the display format